# Swift Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am pretty new to Swift and have come across a puzzling error.

I have a Menu inside an view:

```
            Menu("Report an issue")
            {
                Button("Pothole", action: passReport(rtype: "Pothole"))
                Button("Street Obstruction", action: passReport(rtype: "Street Obstruction"))
                Button("Weather Damage", action: passReport(rtype: "Weather Damage"))
                Button("Vehicular Accident", action: passReport(rtype: "Vehicular Accident"))
                Button("Other Issue", action: passReport(rtype: "Other Issue"))
            }
```

Then, defined within this view is a function named passReport, it looks like so:

```
    func passReport(rtype: String)
    {
        let lat1:String = "\(LocationHelper.currentLocation.latitude)"
        let long1:String = "\(LocationHelper.currentLocation.longitude)"

        dataManager.addReport(id: "ID goes here", latitude: lat1, longitude: long1, reportType: rtype)
        
    }
```

I am getting the error:

`Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'`

on all five lines in my Menu, up until recently, this function had no parameters and worked just fine, I recently added the reportType field to my dataManager and added a parameter to the function, and now it doesn't work. I am sure this is something simple, I checked the other questions but they didn't answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a closure to the button action. And not void like you do now.

You can try

```
Button("Street Obstruction", action: { passReport(rtype: "Street Obstruction") })
```